# No data from desktop heap monitor (dheapmon.exe) on WinXP

Tags: winapi, heap-memory, windows-xp

Has anyone seen this error?  I'm able to install and load the desktop heap monitor but I can't get any data from it:

`C:\kktools\dheapmon8.1\x86>"c:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\symchk.exe" c:\windows\system32\win32k.sys`

C:\kktools\dheapmon8.1\x86>dheapinst.exe -y c:\symbols\
  dheapinst - Desktop Heap Monitor installed successfully

C:\kktools\dheapmon8.1\x86>dheapmon.exe -l
Desktop Heap Information Monitor Tool (Version 8.1.2925.0)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
  Dheapmon - Driver loaded successfully

C:\kktools\dheapmon8.1\x86>dheapmon.exe
Desktop Heap Information Monitor Tool (Version 8.1.2925.0)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
  Dheapmon - Could not detect the required kernel data. Prepare the appropriate symbol file and reinstall dheapmon.

Answer (score 0):

After running the dheapinst.exe program, the Desktop Heap Monitor is installed into "%SystemRoot%\system32\kktools".  You must run the tool from there.